# the solution of Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add an icon button that will navigate to another route **onPressed**, and there's no error until I run the app and it shows me **Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.** What am I missing? Thanks. **I deleted codes inside scaffold to be able to post this question**

```
class SignIn extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(  
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),

    home: Scaffold (

        ),

        body:
 Container(
          child:
 Column(children: [

           Text('Sign In', style: TextStyle(         
            color: Colors.orange,
            fontSize: 60.0) ),
             SizedBox(height:20,),
            TextField(
              
            decoration: InputDecoration(    
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Email',
           
            ),
          ),
           TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(    
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Password',
           
            ),
          ),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),
               ElevatedButton(  
                child: const Text('Sign In'),  
                  onPressed: null,  
              ),  

              SizedBox(height: 15,),
              Text('Forgot Password ?', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),)
            
              
          ],
          
          ),
          
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
        ),

      drawer: Drawer(

    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
          child: Image(image: AssetImage('Images/smsa logo.png'))
        ),




        ListTile(
          
          
          title: Text('My Account'),
          leading: IconButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.push(
            context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyAccount() ));
           }, icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle)
          
        )),
```

Comment: where is this list tile?? Does it have a MaterialApp ancestor? is it inside a popup?

Comment: @pedro pimont   , sorry I'm new to Flutter,  yes it's inside a MaterialApp, But I don't what popup is.

Comment: popup is a dialog. Something that appears above the screen

Comment: can you paste more code? Please maybe the part with your materialapp

Comment: @pedropimont I did now

Comment: ok, Already identified the problem and ill help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even though you have a `MaterialApp` inside your widgets, you don't have access to its `context`, but rather the context which is being passed above the material app. To solve this problem you have to extract the `MaterialApp` in its own widget

This example which you can paste on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id) shows you how to do it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // the context you access here has an MaterialApp above it
    return Text(
      'Hello, World!',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    );
  }
}
```